# Undefined Symbol(s) for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, terminal

So I have been browsing for some time to figure out what is going on with this, but a lot of times it is because a program is missing a `main` or something, but my program has all the needed methods.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

namespace mp = boost::multiprecision;
typedef mp::cpp_int my_int;

bool isPalimdrome(int);
bool isBinaryPalimdrom(std::string);
std::string base10To2(int);
std::string reverse(std::string);

int main() {
    int num = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    while (num < 1000000) {
        std::string num_bin = base10To2(num);
        if (isPalimdrome(num) && isBinaryPalimdrom(num_bin) ){
            sum += num;     
        }
        num++;
    }
    return 0;
}


bool isPalimdrome(int x) {
    std::ostringstream strs;
    strs << x;

    const std::string ori = strs.str();
    const std::string rev = reverse(ori);

    if (rev.compare(ori) == 0) return true;
    return false;
}

bool isBinaryPalimdrome(std::string s) {
    const std::string ori = s;
    const std::string rev = reverse(ori);
    if (rev.compare(ori) == 0) return true;
    return false;
}

std::string base10To2(int x) {
    std::string out = "";
    while (x != 0) {
        if (x % 2 == 0) 
            out += "0";
        else
            out += "1";
        x /= 2;
    }
    return out;
}

std::string reverse(std::string s) {
    std::string result = "";

    for (const char& x : s) {
        result = x + result;
    }
    //std::cout << "This is the original " <<
    //  s << std::endl;
    //std::cout << "This is the reversed " << 
    //  result << std::endl;    
    return result;
}
```

I posted the full code just in case, but I believe it has something to do with my `isBinaryPalimdrome()` function, and this is the error that I get:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "isBinaryPalimdrom(std::string)", referenced from:
      _main in Problem36-cae975.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Problem36] Error 1
```

I am programming on a Mac in Terminal if that matters.

Comment: Your reverse could be replaced with `std::reverse`.

Comment: Do you really need SO's help to find the difference between `isBinaryPalimdrom` and `isBinaryPalimdrome`?

Comment: Both of them are spelt wrong of course, it should be "palindrome"

Comment: @JonathanWakely it's all Greek to me... Should have been παλίνδρομο

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the typo is causing the pain:
you declared:

```
bool isBinaryPalimdrom(std::string);
```

but you defined

```
bool isBinaryPalimdrome(std::string s) 
//                    ^
```

Comment: I am and idiot...Thank you very much..can't believe this threw me off...